# Get Newrelic alert when app not reporting

Tags: monitoring, newrelic

**Background**

```
I have a forever-running scrape-script that I monitor with Newrelic.
```

**Goal**

```
I want to get an email when the script is not reporting to Newrelic.
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think NewRelic is the right kind of tool for this type of monitoring. You'd want to use a service that gets pinged by your scripts on a regular basis, and that informs you if the pings stop coming. One service that can do this is [wdt.io](https://wdt.io) with an inbound timer.